# C++ Observer Patterns - Sticking to "Program to Interfaces" principal

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I’m implementing the Observer Pattern from Head First Design Patterns in C++ and I’m facing a little problem.
I got the error : “class Subject has no member named setNewMeasurments ” on the line `station->setNewMeasurments(0.5,10.0, 7.5);`
It seem that if I want to use polymorphism, the method “`setNewMeasurments`” should be defined in the interface (“Subject”). BUT this violates the principal of "Programming to Interfaces" and I really need polymorphism to make the Observer Pattern work here. Please any comments? Thank you!!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

/**************************************************
***************    Interfaces    ******************
***************************************************/

class Observer
{
    public:
        virtual void update(float temp, float humidity, float pressure) = 0 ;
};

class Subject
{
    protected:
        vector<Observer*> observers; //est-ce une bonne idée ici?  c'est contraire au pattern strategy (separate changing elements from constant ones) -> Visiblement c'est ce qui est fait dans l'UML page 56

    public:
        virtual void registerObserver(Observer* o) = 0;
        virtual void removeObserver(Observer* o)  = 0;
        virtual void notifyObserver() = 0;
};

class DisplayElement
{
    public:
        virtual void display() const = 0 ;
};

/**************************************************
*************    Implementations    ***************
***************************************************/

class WeatherData : public Subject
{
    private:
        float temperature;
        float humidity;
        float pressure;

    public:
        virtual void registerObserver(Observer* o){
            observers.push_back(o); //y'a as un probleme la?
        }
        virtual void removeObserver(Observer* o){
            std::vector<Observer*>::iterator position=std::find(observers.begin(), observers.end(), o);
            if (position != observers.end()) 
                observers.erase(position);
            }
        virtual void notifyObserver()
        {
            for (vector<Observer*>::iterator it=observers.begin() ; it!=observers.end() ; it++)
            {
                (*it)->update(temperature, humidity, pressure);
            }
        }
        void measurmentChanged() {
            notifyObserver();
        }
        void setNewMeasurments(float temp, float hum, float press)
        {
            this->temperature=temp;
            this->humidity=hum;
            this->pressure=press;
            measurmentChanged();
        }       
};

class CurrentConditionsDisplay : public Observer, public DisplayElement
{
    private:
        float temperature;
        float humidity;
        float pressure;
        Subject* weatherData;
        // Faut penser à désallouer cette mémoire dans le destructeur --> exercice!! (le faire à la main puis utiliser le Wrapper)
    public:
        CurrentConditionsDisplay(Subject* w){
            weatherData=w;
            weatherData->registerObserver(this);
        }   
        void update(float temp, float hum, float press){
            temperature=temp;
            humidity=hum;
            pressure=press;
            display();
        }
        void display() const {
            cout << "Current Conditions Displayers  " << endl << endl;
            cout << "Temperature : " << temperature << endl;
            cout << "Humidity : " << temperature << endl;
            cout << "Pressure : " << temperature << endl;
        };
};
int main()
{
    Subject* station=new WeatherData;
    CurrentConditionsDisplay mDisp(station);
    station->setNewMeasurments(0.5,10.0, 7.5);

    delete station;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i will deal with memory management later (probably using a wrapper)

Comment: There's no need to use the base-class `Subject` there, or pointers really (not for this simple test anyway). Just make `station` an instance of `WeatherData`.

Comment: oh yes so i just can do WeatherData* station=new WeatherData and all works fine!!! thank you so much

Comment: @JasBeck but don't. Use references and the stack *whenever you can*. You have no idea how much faster it is.

Comment: @ CoffeeandCode but how can i use polymorphism without any pointer?

Comment: I also wonder whether it is needed to free the memory since we have vector<Observer*> observers in Suject and  Subject* weatherData in CurrentConditionsDisplay. No "new" is called inside those classes so it might not be recquired to free memory?

Comment: @JasBeck like I said, with references. To store polymorphic objects you'll need pointers of course, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that when you write:

```
 Subject* station=new WeatherData;
```

you're telling the compiler that `station` is a Subject, and Subject don't define a function called `setNewMeasurments`.

You have to cast back the poiter `station` to `WeatherData`:

```
((WeatherData*)station)->setNewMeasurments(0.5,10.0, 7.5);
```

or in true C++ as  CoffeeandCode has pointed out:

```
static_cast<WeatherData*>(station)->setNewMeasurments(0.5,10.0, 7.5);
```

However, since `WeatherDate` inherits from `Subject`, you could write directly:

```
WeatherData* station=new WeatherData;
CurrentConditionsDisplay mDisp(station);
station->setNewMeasurments(0.5,10.0, 7.5);
```

Comment: ... and should probably use `dynamic_cast` instead of c-style casts.

Comment: that looks pretty much easier, i agree!

Answer (score 0):

This is how polimorphism is meant to work! If you declare an object to be a `Subject` you can only access the `Subject`'s functions and it's base class' functions.

If you need to call the function `setNewMeasurments` you need to make it accessible by declaring the variable `station`as `WeatherData`.

I think what you actually trying to accomplish is to hide the *implementation* of `WeatherData` and not the entire class. You can accomplish this by moving the function implementations in a *.cpp file. So you would only have the function definitions in your *.h file and the actual code in the *.cpp files.